# From html how to remove duplicated td tag value using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sample html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 65%;">FD Name</th>
        <th style="width:35%;">PDF</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>NT BT Small Cap FD</td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a target="_self" onclick="window.open('URL/2509-pqr-statement.pdf'); return false;">ST</a> (55 kb)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>   <tr>
        <td>NT GB GT FD</td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a target="_self" onclick="window.open('URL/12111-pqr-statement.pdf'); return false;">ST</a> (61 kb)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>   <tr>
        <td>NT GB GT FD</td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a target="_self" onclick="window.open('URL/12111-pqr-statement.pdf'); return false;">ST</a> (61 kb)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>   <tr>
        <td>NT Mutual GB Discovery FD</td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a target="_self" onclick="window.open('URL/4684-pqr-statement.pdf'); return false;">ST</a> (69 kb)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>   <tr>
        <td>NT Mutual GB Discovery FD</td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a target="_self" onclick="window.open('URL/4684-pqr-statement.pdf'); return false;">ST</a> (69 kb)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

How to remove duplicated td values for example NT GB GT FD, NT Mutual GB Discovery FD are duplicated.
Any pointers or ideas using JS/jQuery ?

Comment: Compare cell data, if both are equal then remove the second instance?

Comment: Are you asking about duplicated *rows* or duplicated *cells*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`duplicate` is an object which maps the `first td child` of each `tr`. if those child are never seen inside the object, then `duplicate` will keep it. In the other hand, if those child are already inside `duplicate`, then we will remove the `.parent()` of this `td`, which is its `tr`

```
var duplicate = {};

$('tr td:first-child').each (function () {
    var fdName = $(this).html()

    if (duplicate.hasOwnProperty(fdName)) {
       $(this).parent().remove();
    } else {
       duplicate[fdName] = 'true';
    }
});
```

working jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hdvhtse0/1/

Comment: Do you see any issue with below approach code--->    var seen = {};
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[txt] = true;
});

Answer (score 0):

Use an object to store text for a lookup as you walk down each row. Remove row if text has already been seen

```
var textLookup={};

$('#my-table tbody tr:gt(0)').each(function(){
   var $row = $(this),
       targetText = $row.find('td:first').text().trim();
       // may want to make sure the text isn't empty string also??
       if(textLookup[targetText]){
          $row.remove()
       }
       textLookup[targetText]=true; 
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/as9ebh3b/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Do you see any issue with below approach code---> var seen = {}; $('table tr').each(function() { var txt = $(this).text(); if (seen[txt]) $(this).remove(); else seen[txt] = true; });